# How to run alert message when application in not active

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm looking for a way to show an alert message when the application is not running. Some thing like the iphone clock alarm message. When a time arrives, a message pushes on the iphone screen and ask a Yes/No question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find all the information you need here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

(link updated)

Comment: Yeah... this is a link to the Mac OS X Developer Library, not the iOS one.

Comment: Thanks Alex, But I'm looking for a question box with Yes/No options. Something like the alarm box appearing on screen of iPhone when it fires. UINotification is just a message box, it does not give feedback from user

Comment: you can try to use [UIApplication setKeepAliveTimeout] to execute a function every X seconds (at least 600). in that function you can show an alertview. the setKeepAliveTimeout require to be a VOIP application, so i'm not sure if apple can approve you anyway.